# Yamaha Digital Piano YDP-145: Play MIDI files on piano using built-in voices?

Tags: midi, digital-piano

I recently bought an YDP-145 and I managed to connect it to my computer using USB to HOST. The piano comes with 10 voices and I'm wondering if it's possible to play MIDI files from my computer on the piano with the sound of one of these voices (CFX grand piano specially). Is it technically possible?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The Yamaha page for the [YDP-145](https://europe.yamaha.com/en/products/musical_instruments/pianos/arius/ydp-145/downloads.html) lists several manuals associated with this instrument.
The third manual down the list:

- `YDP-165_YDP-145_YDP-S55_YDP-S35_MIDI Reference`

... explains how to send and receive MIDI data from a computer.  So yes, you should be able to get the digital piano to play midi files with one of the 10 voices that the instrument has.

NB: You'll probably also need to install the USB Driver software that you can find at the top of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed all manual instructions but I still don't feel that it sounds the same. Maybe it's just me. 

I recorded a video as an example, and this time, I connected the piano to my iPhone by using the Smart Pianist app.

I'm still new to playing piano by the way.

https://youtu.be/0J-ihMRjgkk

First I'm playing a MIDI example and after that I'm trying to play the same tune manually.

Comment: @user1276312 Maybe the dynamics/velocity/volume is slightly different, but other than that it sounds the same to me.

Comment: I think the playback from Smart Pianist sounds odd because it's playing each note at exactly same velocity and the timing is a bit off.

Comment: @ojs That's right. MIDI doesn't have the imperfections of human playing.

Comment: @user1276312 It's not imperfections but expression, and MIDI allows quite precise control of velocity and timing if the software that plays back MIDI uses those. On the other hand, it doesn't have half pedal and very little of the expressiveness of instruments other than piano.

Comment: @user1276312 in that video the the timing is nowhere near perfect and that's what makes it terrible. Precise timing with multitasking computers is not completely easy, and the Smart Pianist app probably isn't even trying to get it right.

Comment: @ojs Well.. That has nothing to do with my original question, but thank you anyway for sharing your observations.

Comment: @user1276312 It was a reply to a comment that didn't really have anything to do with the original question either, but that was targeted at me.